# Space cut out by sheaves (and also holomorphic functions)

Tags: terminology, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory

Akhil Mathew [writes](https://amathew.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/analytic-spaces/)

> In particular, we can think of subspaces of an analytic space as **being cut out** by coherent sheaves of ideals.

And in [this (p.1)](https://web.stanford.edu/~ebwarner/AlgGeomSemTalk.pdf) note, I also encountered the same terminology.

> An analytic subspace of $\mathbf C^n$ is a ringed space $(X, \mathscr{H}_X)$ such that $X\subset \mathbf C^n$ is given the Euclidean topology and is locally **cut out** by holomorphic functions.

What does *cut out* mean in these contexts? How do you formally put it?

Comment: You can imagine equations as scissors, "cutting" the shape of the zeroes of the equations. Of course this is pretty subjective and maybe my interpretation is wrong.